# Graphical Layout Editor instantiating custom view but when ran and adding my own custom view via Java, nothing shows

Tags: android, view

So when I add my custom View, Layer (look below for class), to this Relative Layout it doesn't show up

I have this method to change the `Layer`

```
public void setCurrentLayer(int currentLayer) {
    this.currentLayer = currentLayer;
    this.removeAllViews();
    addView(getLayer(currentLayer));
}
```

Layer Class:

```
public Layer(Context context, AttributeSet atrbSet) {
    super(context, atrbSet);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    this.atrbSet = atrbSet;
    levelTiles = new Tile[width][height];

}

public void generateLayer(int layerNumber) {
    if (layerNumber == 0) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                levelTiles[x][y] = new Grass(this.getContext(), atrbSet);
                addTileToLayer(new Grass(this.getContext(), atrbSet));
            }
    } else {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                levelTiles[x][y] = new Stone(this.getContext(), atrbSet);
                addTileToLayer(new Stone(this.getContext(), atrbSet));
            }
    }
}
private void addTileToLayer(Tile tile) {
    addView(tile, params);
}
```

This works ***perfect*** inside the graphical editor. Nothing about it doesn't work. However, when I create a new Layer in Java (i.e. new Layer(context, attributeset)), it shows up blank. I'd like to say same thing for the tiles, but they don't get the chance to show because the `Layer` isn't showing up.

So my question is:

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

If there is any code that you guys think I may have left out, I will add it if you ask.

Progress Update 1: I've set up some log prints, and each `Layer` is reaching the point to where it's created and added

Progress Update 2: I've set up some if(`Layer == null`) statements to throw runtime exceptions if they are, no errors when ran.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by avoiding adding things inside the class extending `View`, and instead by moving everything to my main class.